# Fitting a list of points with TikZ and its \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a list of `N` points (e.g. `{(0,0),(42,7),...,(0,1)}`). I want to use them as coordinates in TikZ, to draw some things. And I would like to `fit` them into a node (using TikZ's `fit` module (cf. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/fit/ or PGF documentation §34) to put a label under them.

If I have, for example, 4 points, I can manually do it, and it works perfectly :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcounter{i}
\setcounter{i}{0}
\foreach \point in
{(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)}
{
    \node[coordinate] (point-\arabic{i}) at \point { };
    \fill (point-\arabic{i}) circle (0.1);
    \stepcounter{i}
}

\node (box) [draw=gray,dashed, inner sep=10pt,fit=(point-0) (point-1) (point-2) (point-3)] {};
\node (label) at (box.south) [below] { blah };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives :

[image]

Now I want to do the same for an arbitrary number of points. I hoped a `\foreach` would work:

```
\node (boxforeach) [draw=gray,dashed, inner sep=10pt,fit= \foreach \j in {0,1,...,3}{(point-\j) } ] {};
```

but all I get are lots of `! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.`.

Is there a mean to get that working? If there isn't, do you have a simple method to calculate the coordinates of the box manually?

Comment: fixed your figure for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I had hoped there'd be a nicer way to do it, but there's nothing in the TikZ manual, so this is what I'd do:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\edef\points{}
\foreach \point [count=\i] in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)} {
    \def\this{point-\i}
    \node[coordinate] (\this) at \point {} ;
    \fill (\this) circle (0.1) ;
    \xdef\points{(\this) \points}
}

\node (box) [draw=gray,dashed, inner sep=10pt,fit=\points] {};
\node (label) at (box.south) [below] { blah };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you haven't seen `\edef` before, it's like `\def` or `\newcommand`, except it expands the definition before assigning it; `\xdef` is equivalent to `\global\edef`, so its effects can escape the foreach.  Essentially, I just build up the list as you construct the points, and then use the result.

I also removed your manual counter and replaced it with the `[count=\i]` option to `\foreach`.  `\foreach` actually has a lot of useful options; I recommend checking out section 51 of the TikZ & PGF manual.

Comment: Going back to the manual counter solution ([count=\i] doesn't work with my version of pgf/tikz), it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a related question [what is the count=\i](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21557/what-is-the-count-i-in-foreach-for)

Answer (score 9):

This is a hack of the fit library that should work in most cases (the only altered original macro is `\tikz@lib@fit@scan` to allow a `\foreach` parsing).

Note that the fit work is done inside a `\foreach` (see `\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@` in `\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach`), so changes to dimensions must be made `\global`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgf@stop{\pgfutil@gobble}{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\foreach{\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach}{%
      \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle}}}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach\foreach#1in#2#3{%
  \foreach #1 in {#2}
  {\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#3}
  \tikz@lib@fit@scan}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#1{%
  \iftikz@shapeborder
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{west}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{east}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{north}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{south}}%
  \else
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\pgf@xa=\pgf@xa
  \global\pgf@ya=\pgf@ya
  \global\pgf@xb=\pgf@xb
  \global\pgf@yb=\pgf@yb}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \point [count=\i] in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2),(3,3),(-1,-1)}{%
    \node[coordinate] (point-\i) at \point {};
    \fill (point-\i) circle (0.1);}
  \node [draw=gray,dashed,inner sep=10pt,
    fit = \foreach \j in {1,2,...,4}{(point-\j) }] (boxforeach1) {}; 
  \node [draw=red,dashed, inner sep=10pt,
    fit = (point-1) \foreach \j in {2,...,5}{(point-\j) }] (boxforeach2) {}; 
  \node [draw=blue,dashed, inner sep=10pt,
    fit = (point-1) \foreach \j in {2,...,5}{(point-\j) } (point-6)] 
    (boxforeach3) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that a feature request has been added at the sourceforge project web page.

Comment: +1 This code works great! Just wondering if there any updates as to whether this feature has been implemented?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a `.List` handler can be helpful in other cases, too?

The second TikZ picture shows [cjorssen’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8425/cjorssen) examples from [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40094/16595). Of course, with the `.List` handler, in all cases one would just do `{(point-1),...,(point-<last>)}` but I wanted to show how one would need to give an example that does not fit in the scheme.

#### Thoughts

PGFkeys offers with the `.list` handler already a `\foreach` alternative that doesn’t group its content (it actually does nearly the same), but what would be the benefit (besides checking whether `\foreach` is defined)? Maybe

I guess, it wouldn’t be too hard to implement a `.foreach` handler so that one could use the full power of a `\foreach` loop (multiple variables, options like `count`, `evaluate` and so on) …

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{%
  .List/.code={%
    \let\pgfkeys@global@temp\pgfutil@empty
    \foreach \pgfkeys@temp in{#1}{
      \ifx\pgfkeys@global@temp\pgfutil@empty
        \global\let\pgfkeys@global@temp\pgfkeys@temp
      \else
        \expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\pgfkeys@global@temp\expandafter
          {\pgfkeys@temp}%
      \fi}%
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfkeys@global@temp}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \point[count=\cnt from 0] in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)}
  \fill \point circle[radius=.1] coordinate (point-\cnt);

\node[label=below:blah, draw=gray, dashed, inner sep=+10pt,
  fit/.List={(point-0),(point-...),(point-3)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, dashed, inner sep=+10pt}]
  \foreach \point [count=\cnt] in {(0,0), (0,2), (2,0), (2,2), (3,3), (-1,-1)}
    \fill \point circle[radius=.1] coordinate (point-\cnt);
  \node[gray, fit/.List={(point-1),(point-...),(point-4)}]  {}; 
  \node[red,  fit/.List={(point-1),(point-2),(point-...),(point-5)}]  {}; 
  \node[blue, fit/.List={(point-1),(point-2),(point-...),(point-5),(point-6)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will do the job:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{i}
\setcounter{i}{0}
\foreach \point in
{(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)}
{
    \node[coordinate] (point-\arabic{i}) at \point { };
    \fill (point-\arabic{i}) circle (0.1);
    \stepcounter{i}
}

\path (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east)
node[midway, below] {blah}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This example simply uses the current bounding box.

Comment: I looked a bit too quickly at your answer, it would also work in this case, but not if this is part of a bigger picture. However, there is a `local bounding box` option to {scope}'s. In my case, it would be more elegant, but it doesn't allow to "fit" points that are defined at different places. But thanks.