# additional curly braces around matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, braces

I would like to have matrix like this one:
[image]

I know how to make color frames in tikz, but I havee problems with braces.
I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} %do robienia mini macierzy
%           linki w spisie tresci
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} % do kolorowych macierzy
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}



\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
  \node (#1) {\strut};}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
    v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} & \tikzmark{F1p} v_{1,3}  \tikzmark{F1k} & \tikzmark{F2p} \textcolor{white}{v_{1,4}}  \tikzmark{F2k}&  &   \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
    \tikzmark{E1p} v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4}   & &   \\
     & &  v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \\
    \tikzmark{E1k} & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    & &  & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
  \end{array}\right]
\end{equation}



\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt}]
\draw[decorate,thick] (F1p.north) -- (F1k.north)
      node [midway,above=5pt] {$F'$};
\draw[decorate,thick] (F2p.north) -- (F2k.north)
      node [midway,above=5pt] {$F''$};

\draw [decorate,thick,xshift=-2pt,yshift=0pt]
(E1p) -- (E1k) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] 
{\footnotesize $P_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but it gives the following result: 
[image]

I only know a bit how to make upper braces. 
How should I make it properly?

I tried to use the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} %do robienia mini macierzy
%           linki w spisie tresci
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} % do kolorowych macierzy
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}



\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
  \node (#1) {\strut};}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=3pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-3pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=2pt,column sep=1em,row sep=0.5em,nodes={inner sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffseth{0.5em}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffsetv{0.2em}


\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceright[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.north west)!(#1-#3-1.south west)!(#1.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
        -- node[left=2pt] {#4} 
        ($(#1.north west)!(#1-#2-1.north west)!(#1.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.north east)!(#1-#2-1.north east)!(#1.south east)+(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
        -- node[right=2pt] {#4} 
        ($(#1.north east)!(#1-#3-1.south east)!(#1.south east)+(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracetop[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.north west)!(#1-1-#2.north west)!(#1.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$)
        -- node[above=2pt] {#4} 
        ($(#1.north west)!(#1-1-#3.north east)!(#1.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracebottom[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.south west)!(#1-1-#3.south east)!(#1.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$)
        -- node[below=2pt] {#4} 
        ($(#1.south west)!(#1-1-#2.south west)!(#1.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);
}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} = 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=4pt,row sep=1em] (m)  
    {
    v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} & \tikzmark{F1p} v_{1,3}  \tikzmark{F1k} & \tikzmark{F2p} \textcolor{white}{v_{1,4}}  \tikzmark{F2k}&  &   \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
    \tikzmark{E1p} v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4}   & &   \\
     & &  v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \\
    \tikzmark{E1k} & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    & &  & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
    };

    % Braces     
    \mymatrixbraceright{1}{3}{$B'$}
    \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$}
%    \mymatrixbracetop{1}{3}{$C'$}
%    \mymatrixbracetop{4}{6}{$C''$}
%    \mymatrixbracebottom{3}{3}{$F'$}
%    \mymatrixbracebottom{4}{4}{$F''$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

but it gives the error: "package pgf error: no shape named m-4-1 is known \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$}"

works much better, after changing corresponding line to:

```
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=2pt,column sep=1em,row sep=0.5em,nodes={inner sep=0pt}}}
```

but still there is a gap. How to delete the gap or make it smaller?
[image]

Comment: Could [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443057/74459) help? It would require to change your matrix to a Tikz matrix, but that might also help with adding the colored areas.

Comment: thanks, but I still have problems. After implementation of the answer I obtain errors with drawing brace 4-6. I mean:
    \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$} , gives error no shape named m-4-1

Comment: If you could update your question to include what you have achieved so far, I can try something :)

Comment: You only have to add the `nodes in empty cells` key to your matrix and it should work.

Comment: thanks! now it's working, but not perfect. I obtained [link] (http://i.imgur.com/Ob7F8FQ.png). Why the second bracket is shorter than the upper and there is so big gap between them?

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) by clicking on the arrows next to the score. If any of the answers solve your problem then mark the best solution as an [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) by clicking on the checkmark ✓. Both Milo and J Leon V. have given excellent complete answers and, as always, Max Snippe's answer is very elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An (maybe simpler) alternative to @Milo's excellent answer, I've given all nodes a minimum size.

[image]

I also changed the `\mymatrixbrace<side>` commands slightly so you don't need the `calc` library anymore.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} %do robienia mini macierzy
%           linki w spisie tresci
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} % do kolorowych macierzy
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration={brace},every left delimiter/.style={xshift=8pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-8pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},inner sep=1pt,outer sep=1.5pt,column sep=2pt,row sep=2pt,nodes={minimum width=20pt,minimum height=10pt,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}

\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceright[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.west|-#1-#3-1.south west) -- node[left=2pt] {#4} (#1.west|-#1-#2-1.north west);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.north east) -- node[right=2pt] {#4} (#1.east|-#1-#3-1.south east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracetop[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.north-|#1-1-#2.north west) -- node[above=2pt] {#4} (#1.north-|#1-1-#3.north east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracebottom[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.south-|#1-1-#2.north east) -- node[below=2pt] {#4} (#1.south-|#1-1-#3.north west);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{X} = 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-0.5ex},mymatrixenv]
        \matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=4pt] (m)  
        {
        v_{1,1} & v_{1,2} & v_{1,3} &         &         &         \\
        v_{2,1} & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} &         &         &         \\
        v_{3,1} & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4} &         &         \\
                &         & v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5} & v_{4,6} \\
                &         &         & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6} \\
                &         &         & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
        };
    
        % Braces     
        \mymatrixbraceright{1}{3}{$B'$}
        \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{1}{3}{$C'$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{4}{6}{$C''$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{3}{3}{$F'$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{4}{4}{$F''$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{3}{3}{$E'$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{4}{4}{$E''$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Edit: Adjusted `\mymatrixbraceleft` according to Daniel H.'s comment

Comment: I couldn't get the right-hand side braces to brace more than one row. Changing the "mymatrixbraceleft" command to <\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.north east) -- node[right=2pt] {#4} (#1.east|-#1-#3-1.south east);
}> fixed it :)

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**

Here is one way to do it. The steps are laid out in my original answer below. Not claiming this is the best way, one could optimise the steps certainly, but it works for this particular matrix.

Seeing as you need to draw coloured boxes around certain subsets of this matrix anyway, you can use the `fit` library for that and subsequently use those coordinates to help guide where your braces go.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,fit}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=4.7pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-4.7pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=2pt,column sep=1em,row sep=0.5em,nodes={inner sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}

% The hack required for foreach loops in fit. Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/fitting-a-list-of-points-with-tikz-and-its-foreach?noredirect=1&lq=1
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgf@stop{\pgfutil@gobble}{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\foreach{\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach}{%
      \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle}}}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach\foreach#1in#2#3{%
  \foreach #1 in {#2}
  {\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#3}
  \tikz@lib@fit@scan}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#1{%
  \iftikz@shapeborder
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{west}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{east}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{north}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{south}}%
  \else
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\pgf@xa=\pgf@xa
  \global\pgf@ya=\pgf@ya
  \global\pgf@xb=\pgf@xb
  \global\pgf@yb=\pgf@yb}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,outer ysep=0.7pt,inner sep=4pt,row sep=1em] (m)  
    {
    v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} &  v_{1,3}  & &  &   \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
   v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4}   & &   \\
     & &  v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \\
    & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    & &  & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
    };

% Colours
\definecolor{brightpurple}{HTML}{C151EF}

% Fitting - note to get a \foreach loop in these fits requires the hack from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/fitting-a-list-of-points-with-tikz-and-its-foreach
\node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{(m-\X-1)}
            \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{(m-\X-2)}
            \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{(m-\X-3)}]
            [draw=green, thick,inner sep=2.6pt] (fit-a) {};

\node [fit= \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{(m-\X-4)}
            \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{(m-\X-5)}
            \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{(m-\X-6)}]
            [draw=cyan, thick,inner sep=2.6pt] (fit-b) {};

\node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,4}{(m-\X-3)}] [draw=brightpurple,fill=brightpurple,fill opacity=0.1, thick,inner sep=1.8pt] (fit-purple-a) {};
\node [fit= \foreach \X in {3,...,6}{(m-\X-4)}] [draw=brightpurple,fill=brightpurple,fill opacity=0.1, thick,inner sep=1.8pt]  (fit-purple-b) {};       
\node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,4}{(m-3-\X)}] [draw=brown,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.1, thick,inner sep=1pt] (fit-brown-a) {};   \node [fit= \foreach \X in {3,...,6}{(m-4-\X)}] [draw=brown,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.1, thick,inner sep=1pt] (fit-brown-b) {}; 
\node [fit = (m-3-3) (m-3-4) (m-4-3) (m-4-4)] [draw=orange,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.1, thick,inner sep=2.6pt] {};

% FINDING VERTICAL MIDPOINT
 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{
            (m-\X-1)}] (fit-one)  {}; 
 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{
            (m-\X-6)}] (fit-two)  {}; 
\path (fit-one.south) -- (fit-two.north) coordinate[midway] (X);

% FINDING HORIZONTAL MIDPOINT
 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{
            (m-1-\X)}] (fit-one)  {}; 
 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{
            (m-6-\X)}] (fit-two)  {}; 
\path (fit-one.east) -- (fit-two.west) coordinate[midway] (Y);

\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffseth{0.3em}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffsetv{0.3em}

% LHS BRACES
\draw [mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!(fit-a.south)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)   -- node[left=2pt] {$B'$}  ($(m.north west)!(fit-a.north)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);
\draw [mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!(fit-b.south)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$) -- node[left=2pt] {$B''$} ($(m.north west)!(fit-b.north)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);

% RHS BRACES
\draw [mymatrixbrace]  ($(m.north east)!([yshift=-0.02cm]X)!(m.south east)+(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)   -- node[right=2pt] {$E''$} ($(m.north east)!(fit-brown-b.south)!(m.south east)+(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);
 \draw [mymatrixbrace]  ($(m.north east)!(fit-brown-a.north)!(m.south east)+(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$) --node[right=2pt] {$E'$}   ($(m.north east)! ([yshift=+0.02cm]X)!(m.south east)+(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);

% TOP BRACES       
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!([xshift=0.05cm]Y)!(m.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$) -- node[above=2pt] {$C''$}  ($(m.north west)!(fit-b.east)!(m.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!(fit-a.west)!(m.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$)-- node[above=2pt] {$C'$}   ($(m.north west)!([xshift=-0.05cm]Y)!(m.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);

% BOTTOM BRACES      
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(m.south west)!([xshift=-0.05cm]Y)!(m.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$)-- node[below=2pt] {$F'$}  ($(m.south west)!(fit-purple-a.west)!(m.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);   
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(m.south west)!(fit-purple-b.east)!(m.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$) -- node[below=2pt] {$F''$} ($(m.south west)!([xshift=0.05cm]Y)!(m.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here is a proof of concept to show how you can remove the gap between the two braces. I've drawn boxes around all the nodes to illustrate where the boundaries lie. The reason why in your example above the lower bracket `B''` was shorter than the upper bracket `B'` was because it was only measuring the coordinates from cells in the first column. (It's just a limitation of the custom command `\mymatrixbraceright` as its been defined in your MWE). But see how in the first column cell (6,1) has a smaller bounding box than say cell (6,6)?

The method I've used here is to perform a fit around cells (1,1), (2,1) and (3,1) and perform a fit around cells (4,6), (5,6) and (6,6). Using these two fits I can find the midway point between them. This takes inspiration from [Automatically find which nodes are closest, to aid drawing lines within a TikZ matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443183/automatically-find-which-nodes-are-closest-to-aid-drawing-lines-within-a-tikz-m).

Using this midpoint I can then manually draw the braces starting from the top of (1,1) to (X). And from (X) to the bottom of (6,6).

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,fit}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=3pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-3pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=2pt,column sep=1em,row sep=0.5em,nodes={inner sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffseth{0.5em}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffsetv{0em}


% CODE from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/fitting-a-list-of-points-with-tikz-and-its-foreach?noredirect=1&lq=1
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgf@stop{\pgfutil@gobble}{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\foreach{\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach}{%
      \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle}}}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach\foreach#1in#2#3{%
  \foreach #1 in {#2}
  {\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#3}
  \tikz@lib@fit@scan}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#1{%
  \iftikz@shapeborder
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{west}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{east}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{north}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{south}}%
  \else
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\pgf@xa=\pgf@xa
  \global\pgf@ya=\pgf@ya
  \global\pgf@xb=\pgf@xb
  \global\pgf@yb=\pgf@yb}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=4pt,row sep=1em,draw,nodes={draw}] (m)  
    {
    v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} &  v_{1,3}  & &  &   \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
   v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4}   & &   \\
     & &  v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \\
    & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    & &  & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
    };

 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{
            (m-\X-1)}] (fit-a) [draw] {}; 
 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{
            (m-\X-6)}] (fit-b) [draw] {}; 
\path (fit-a.south) -- (fit-b.north) coordinate[midway] (X);

\draw [mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!(X)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
        -- node[left=2pt] {$B'$} 
        ($(m.north west)!(m-1-1.north west)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);

\draw [mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!(m-6-6.south)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
        -- node[left=2pt] {$B'$} 
        ($(m.north west)!(X)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To get something closer to the image you posted. I suggest adding shifting the y coordinate of `(X)` slightly. Here I've used `yshift=0.05cm` on the upper brace and `yshift=-0.05cm` on the lower brace. Also, to make the braces reach the extremities of the matrix bracket, instead of drawing them from the north boundary of (1,1) and the south boundary of (6,6), I've changed it so they are drawn from `m.north` and from `m.south`. I've also added `outer ysep=0.5pt` to increase the length of the square brackets slightly. These numbers can be played with as you see fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,fit}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=3pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-3pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=2pt,column sep=1em,row sep=0.5em,nodes={inner sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffseth{0.5em}
\newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffsetv{0em}


% CODE from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/fitting-a-list-of-points-with-tikz-and-its-foreach?noredirect=1&lq=1
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgf@stop{\pgfutil@gobble}{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\foreach{\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach}{%
      \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle}}}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach\foreach#1in#2#3{%
  \foreach #1 in {#2}
  {\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#3}
  \tikz@lib@fit@scan}
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle@foreach@#1{%
  \iftikz@shapeborder
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{west}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{east}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{north}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{%
      \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{south}}%
  \else
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\pgf@xa=\pgf@xa
  \global\pgf@ya=\pgf@ya
  \global\pgf@xb=\pgf@xb
  \global\pgf@yb=\pgf@yb}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,outer ysep=0.5pt,inner sep=4pt,row sep=1em] (m)  
    {
    v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} &  v_{1,3}  & &  &   \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
   v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4}   & &   \\
     & &  v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \\
    & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    & &  & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
    };

 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{
            (m-\X-1)}] (fit-a)  {}; 
 \node [fit= \foreach \X in {4,...,6}{
            (m-\X-6)}] (fit-b)  {}; 
\path (fit-a.south) -- (fit-b.north) coordinate[midway] (X);

\draw [mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!([yshift=0.05cm]X)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
        -- node[left=2pt] {$B'$} 
        ($(m.north west)!(m.north west)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);

\draw [mymatrixbrace] ($(m.north west)!(m.south)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
        -- node[left=2pt] {$B''$} 
        ($(m.north west)!([yshift=-0.05cm]X)!(m.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 from a marmot ;-)

Comment: +1 for everybody for the patience and time that everyone has dedicated.

Answer (score 9):

An option including some tricks for the `patterns`, using `fit` to highlight elements and get the coordinates for the external braces; I use an Auxiliar node to find the intersectións between highlighted boxes to draw the braces, also to draw the brackets for the matrix and control the separations with `inne xsep`, and `inner ysep`; finally I modify the left and right delimiter to increase the line thickness.

RESULT in article class:

[image]

MWE in article class:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools} %do robienia mini macierzy
%           linki w spisie tresci
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} % do kolorowych macierzy
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{21EE7D}
\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{BB1BFF}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}
%Create a new patern for firefox and adobe reader from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219808/154390
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east lines b}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{20pt}{20pt}}{\pgfqpoint{20pt}{20pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{6pt}
    %Principal line
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{20pt}{20pt}}
    %Complement line north east
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{16pt}{-4pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{24pt}{4pt}}
    %Complement line south west
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-4pt}{16pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{24pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{X} = 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Global config
        baseline=0cm,
        >=latex,
        line width=1pt,
        %Styles
        Brace/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                brace,
                amplitude=2pt,
                raise=-7pt
            }
        },
        Brackets/.style={
            left delimiter={[},
            right delimiter={]}
        },
        every left delimiter/.style={
                xshift=2pt,
                xscale=1.5,
                transform shape
        },
        every right delimiter/.style={
                xshift=-2pt,
                xscale=1.5,
                transform shape
        },
        Matrix/.style={
            matrix of math nodes,
            text height=1.5ex,
            text depth=0.5ex,
            text width=4ex,
            align=center,
            column sep=7pt,
            row sep=7pt,
            nodes in empty cells,
        },
        HLbox/.style={
            rectangle,
            draw,
            line width=1.5pt,
            fill,
            fill opacity=0.1,   
        },
        HLPbox/.style={
            thick,
            pattern=north east lines b,         
        }
        ]

        \matrix[Matrix] at (0,0) (M1){ % Matrix contents  
            v_{1,1}  & v_{1,2} & v_{1,3} &            &            &            \\
            v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} &            &            &            \\
            v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4} &            &            \\
            &            & v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5} & v_{4,6} \\
            &            &            & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6} \\
            &            &            & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
        };

        %Hightlight elements in background layer
        \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
        \node[HLPbox,pattern color=orange!50,draw=orange,inner sep=2pt,fit=(M1-3-3)(M1-4-4)](F){};
        \node[HLbox,mygreen,inner sep=1pt,fit=(M1-1-1)(M1-3-3)](C1){};
        \node[HLbox,cyan,inner sep=1pt,fit=(M1-4-4)(M1-6-6)](C2){};
        \node[HLbox,brown,inner sep=-3pt,fit=(M1-3-1)(M1-3-4)](E1){};
        \node[HLbox,brown,inner sep=-3pt,fit=(M1-4-3)(M1-4-6)](E2){};
        \node[HLbox,mypurple,inner sep= -1pt,fit=(M1-1-3)(M1-4-3)](F1){};
        \node[HLbox,mypurple,inner sep= -1pt,fit=(M1-3-4)(M1-6-4)](F2){};
        \end{scope}

        %Delimiters
        \node[Brackets,inner xsep=-6pt,inner ysep=0.5pt,fit=(M1)](BM1){};
        % Auxiliar to separate external braces
        \node[inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=10pt,fit=(M1)](AUX){};

        % Drawing the braces.
        %Above
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.90 -| C1.180) -- (AUX.90 -| C1.0) node[midway,above]{$C'$};
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.90 -| C2.180) -- (AUX.90 -| C2.0) node[midway,above]{$C''$};
        %below
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.270 -| F1.0) -- (AUX.270 -| F1.180) node[midway,below]{$F'$};
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.270 -| F2.0) -- (AUX.270 -| F2.180) node[midway,below]{$F''$};
        %Left
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.180 |- C1.270) -- (AUX.180 |- C1.90) node[midway,left]{$B'$};
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.180 |- C2.270) -- (AUX.180 |- C2.90) node[midway,left]{$B''$};
        %Right
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.0 |- E1.90) -- (AUX.0 |- E1.270) node[midway,right]{$E'$};
        \draw[Brace] (AUX.0 |- E2.90) -- (AUX.0 |- E2.270) node[midway,right]{$E''$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

RESULT in standalone class:
[image]
MWE in standalone class:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=14pt]{standalone}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{21EE7D}
\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{BB1BFF}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}

%Create a new patern for firefox and adobe reader from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219808/154390
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east lines b}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{20pt}{20pt}}{\pgfqpoint{20pt}{20pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{6pt}
  %Principal line
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{20pt}{20pt}}
  %Complement line north east
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{16pt}{-4pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{24pt}{4pt}}
  %Complement line south west
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-4pt}{16pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{24pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Global config
        baseline=0cm,
        >=latex,
        line width=1pt,
        %Styles
        Brace/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                brace,
                amplitude=2pt,
                raise=-7pt
            }
        },
        Brackets/.style={
            left delimiter={[},
            right delimiter={]}
        },
        every left delimiter/.style={
                xshift=2.5pt,
                xscale=1.5,
                transform shape
            },
            every right delimiter/.style={
                xshift=-2.5pt,
                xscale=1.5,
                transform shape
            },
        Matrix/.style={
            matrix of math nodes,
            text height=1.5ex,
            text depth=0.5ex,
            text width=4ex,
            align=center,
            column sep=7pt,
            row sep=7pt,
            nodes in empty cells,
        },
        HLbox/.style={
            rectangle,
            draw,
            line width=1.5pt,
            fill,
            fill opacity=0.1,   
        },
        HLPbox/.style={
            thick,
            pattern=north east lines b,         
        }
    ]

    \matrix[Matrix] at (0,0) (M1){ % Matrix contents  
    v_{1,1}  & v_{1,2} & v_{1,3} &            &            &            \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} &            &            &            \\
    v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4} &            &            \\
                &            & v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5} & v_{4,6} \\
                &            &            & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6} \\
                &            &            & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
    };

    %Hightlight elements in background layer
    \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
    \node[HLPbox,pattern color=orange!50,draw=orange,inner sep=2pt,fit=(M1-3-3)(M1-4-4)](F){};
    \node[HLbox,mygreen,inner sep=1pt,fit=(M1-1-1)(M1-3-3)](C1){};
    \node[HLbox,cyan,inner sep=1pt,fit=(M1-4-4)(M1-6-6)](C2){};
    \node[HLbox,brown,inner sep=-3pt,fit=(M1-3-1)(M1-3-4)](E1){};
    \node[HLbox,brown,inner sep=-3pt,fit=(M1-4-3)(M1-4-6)](E2){};
    \node[HLbox,mypurple,inner sep= -1pt,fit=(M1-1-3)(M1-4-3)](F1){};
    \node[HLbox,mypurple,inner sep= -1pt,fit=(M1-3-4)(M1-6-4)](F2){};
    \end{scope}

    %Delimiters
    \node[Brackets,inner xsep=-6pt,inner ysep=0.5pt,fit=(M1)](BM1){};
    % Auxiliar to separate external braces
    \node[inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=10pt,fit=(M1)](AUX){};

    % Drawing the braces.
    %Above
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.90 -| C1.180) -- (AUX.90 -| C1.0) node[midway,above]{$C'$};
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.90 -| C2.180) -- (AUX.90 -| C2.0) node[midway,above]{$C''$};
    %below
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.270 -| F1.0) -- (AUX.270 -| F1.180) node[midway,below]{$F'$};
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.270 -| F2.0) -- (AUX.270 -| F2.180) node[midway,below]{$F''$};
    %Left
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.180 |- C1.270) -- (AUX.180 |- C1.90) node[midway,left]{$B'$};
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.180 |- C2.270) -- (AUX.180 |- C2.90) node[midway,left]{$B''$};
    %Right
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.0 |- E1.90) -- (AUX.0 |- E1.270) node[midway,right]{$E'$};
    \draw[Brace] (AUX.0 |- E2.90) -- (AUX.0 |- E2.270) node[midway,right]{$E''$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 A very nice answer!

Comment: +1 I really should learn about the fit library:)

Comment: +1 for this as well as two other recent great answers ... maybe you could reconsider your attitude towards nesting `tikzpicture`s? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using a `matrix of nodes`. The main difficulty is in placing the braces across multiple rows or columns. For this I use some customised trickery and define two `pics`, called `leftbrace` and `overbrace`, that place the brace given the row and column indices and the label.

Here's the result:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,patterns,calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer

\newdimen\leftpt
\newdimen\righpt
\tikzset{%
  pics/overbrace/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{%
    % a pic for putting an underbrace under certain columns
    % #1 = left column
    % #2 = right column index
    % #3 = label text
    code = {
       \pgfextractx\leftpt{\pgfpointanchor{M-1-#1}{north west}}  % x-coords of columns
       \pgfextractx\righpt{\pgfpointanchor{M-1-#2}{north east}}
       % draw the delimiter with the correct width
       \node[rectangle, above delimiter={\{}, minimum width=\the\dimexpr\righpt-\leftpt+1pt,
             label={[yshift=2mm]above:$\scriptscriptstyle #3$}]
             at ($ (M-1-#1)!0.5!(M-1-#2)+(0,0.2) $){};
       }
   },
   pics/leftbrace/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{%
   % a pic for putting a brace to the left of certain rows
   % #1 = top row index
   % #2 = bottom row index
   % #3 = label text
   code = {
       \pgfextracty\leftpt{\pgfpointanchor{M-#1-1}{north west}}  % y-coords of columns
       \pgfextracty\righpt{\pgfpointanchor{M-#2-1}{south west}}
       % draw the delimiter with the correct width
       \node[rectangle, left delimiter={\{}, minimum height=\dimexpr\leftpt-\righpt+1pt,
             label={[xshift=-2mm]left:$\scriptscriptstyle #3$}]
             at ($ (M-#1-1)!0.5!(M-#2-1)+(-0.6,0) $){};
       }
   },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{purple}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{brown}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{orange}
  \pgfsetlayers{purple,brown,orange,main}  % set the order of the layers (main is the standard layer)
  \begin{tikzpicture}[draw/.append style={thick}]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
                left delimiter={[},
                right delimiter={]},
    ]{
         v_{1,1} & v_{1,2} & v_{1,3} &         &         &   \\
         v_{2,1} & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} &         &         &   \\
         v_{3,1} & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4} &         &   \\
                 &         & v_{4,3} & v_{4,4} & v_{4,5} & v_{4,6} \\
                 &         &         & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
                 &         &         & v_{6,4} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \\
     };
     \pic{leftbrace={1,3,B'}};
     \pic{leftbrace={4,6,B''}};
     \pic{overbrace={1,3,C'}};
     \pic{overbrace={4,6,C''}};
     \node[minimum height=2mm, right delimiter={\}},
           label={[xshift=1mm,yshift=0.6mm]right:$\scriptscriptstyle E'$}] at ($ (M-3-6)+(0.5,0) $){};
     \node[minimum height=2mm, right delimiter={\}},
           label={[xshift=1mm,yshift=0.6mm]right:$\scriptscriptstyle E''$}] at ($ (M-4-6)+(0.5,0) $){};
     \node[minimum width=6mm, below delimiter={\}},
           label={[yshift=-1mm]below:$\scriptscriptstyle F'$}] at ($ (M-6-3)+(0,-0.2) $){};
     \node[minimum width=6mm, below delimiter={\}},
           label={[yshift=-1mm]below:$\scriptscriptstyle F''$}] at ($ (M-6-4)+(0,-0.2) $){};
     \draw[ForestGreen] (M-1-1.north west) rectangle (M-3-3.south east);
     \draw[cyan] (M-4-4.north west) rectangle (M-6-6.south east);
     \begin{pgfonlayer}{purple}    % select the background layer
       \draw[BlueViolet,fill=LightPink,opacity=0.5]
          ($ (0.04,-0.04)+(M-1-3.north west) $) rectangle ($ (-0.04,0.04)+(M-4-3.south east) $);
       \draw[BlueViolet,fill=LightPink,opacity=0.5]
          ($ (0.04,-0.04)+(M-3-4.north west) $) rectangle ($ (-0.04,0.04)+(M-6-4.south east) $);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
     \begin{pgfonlayer}{brown}    % select the background layer
       \draw[FireBrick,fill=Moccasin,opacity=0.5]
         ($ (0.08,-0.08)+(M-3-1.north west) $) rectangle ($ (-0.08,0.08)+(M-3-4.south east) $);
       \draw[FireBrick,fill=Moccasin,opacity=0.5]
         ($ (0.08,-0.08)+(M-4-3.north west) $) rectangle ($ (-0.08,0.08)+(M-4-6.south east) $);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
     \begin{pgfonlayer}{orange}    % select the background layer
       \draw[orange, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, opacity=0.5]
         ($ (0.04,-0.04)+(M-3-3.north west) $) rectangle ($ (-0.04,0.04)+(M-4-4.south east) $);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```